# AVAsset Unsupported URL

Tags: ios, url, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to load a video downloaded from the internet stored in the Documents directory. However when I try I keep getting: error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL"

```
let dstURL = URL(string: dstPath)!
let asset = AVAsset(url: dstURL)
asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["tracks", "playable"]) {
    var error: NSError?
    let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "tracks", error: &error)
      if error != nil {
          print("status: \(status), error: \(error!)")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using URL(fileUrlWithPath:) instead URL(string:) ?

Comment: Thank You ! That seemed to be the problem, but I also removed space from the file.

Comment: Dear @andrehungaro, Thank you for supporting to the SO, you can add your answer below, then cluelessatmaths can mark as correct answer :) Best.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `URL(fileUrlWithPath:)` instead of `URL(string:)`

Answer (score 0):

While you can use `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`, it has been deprecated on almost every platform (e.g. since macOS 13.3). You should be using `URL(string:)` instead and make *very sure* that your URL is complete (i.e. does it have a scheme?)

As an example,

```swift
guard var components = URLComponents(string: path) else {
  throw UserError.invalidPath(path)
}

// We're assuming that `path` didn't have this set (e.g. it's an absolute path and just assumes).
components.scheme = "file"

guard let url = components.url else {
  throw UserError.invalidPath(path)
}

return url
```